# Read all mysql database items with the ID of the user

Tags: php, android, mysql

Hello guys I am implementing something that reads all the mysql database items aand display it in listview but with a WHERE clause (`SELECT * FROM tb_class_record WHERE instructor_id = '?'`) something like that.
what I am aiming is when I logged in with the ID of 'INST-20131296' so only the items that have an ID of 'INST-20131296' will be shown. And same with the other users with different ID. Here is the Home Page as you can see I am logged in with the ID of 'INST-20131296'
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkNYU.jpg

and this is the Class Record Page where the items populated
https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2MCH.jpg

my problem is when I logged in the populated listview is showing all of the items with different ID's what I want is it should be displaying the items that have my user ID e.g INST-20131296

here is my php script:

```
<?php   
$link = mysql_pconnect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Could not connect");
mysql_select_db("dbmobile_class_record") or die("Could not select database");

$arr = array();

$rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tb_class_record ");

while($obj = mysql_fetch_object($rs)) {
$arr[] = $obj;
}
echo '{"class_records":'.json_encode($arr).'}';
?>
```

This is my java file

```
public class ClassRecord extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ListView mylistView;
    String text;
    TextView inst_id, desc, sc, sched,hour, day, room, acad;
    FloatingActionButton fab;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> classrecordList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    private static String url = "http://192.168.0.106/MobileClassRecord/getClassRecord.php";

    private static final String TAG_CR = "class_records";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "instructor_id";
    private static final String TAG_DESC = "description";
    private static final String TAG_SC = "subj_code";
    private static final String TAG_SCHED = "sched_type";
    private static final String TAG_HOUR = "hour";
    private static final String TAG_DAY = "day";
    private static final String TAG_RM = "room";
    private static final String TAG_ACAD = "acad";

    JSONArray classrecord = null;


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ClassRecord.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_class_record);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent fabIntent = new Intent(ClassRecord.this, AddClassRecord.class);
                startActivity(fabIntent);

            }
        });
        new JSONParse().execute();
        classrecordList =new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    }

    class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject>{
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            inst_id = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.inst_id);
            desc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.desc);
            sc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.subj_code);
            sched= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sched);
            hour=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.hour);
            day=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.day);
            room = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.room);
            acad = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.acad);
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ClassRecord.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data from Database...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
            return json;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonObject) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            try {
                classrecord = jsonObject.getJSONArray(TAG_CR);
                for (int i = 0; i < classrecord.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject c = classrecord.getJSONObject(i);

                    final String Inst_id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String Desc = c.getString(TAG_DESC);
                    String Sc = c.getString(TAG_SC);
                    String Sched = c.getString(TAG_SCHED);
                    String Hour = c.getString(TAG_HOUR);
                    String Day = c.getString(TAG_DAY);
                    String Rm = c.getString(TAG_RM);
                    String Acad = c.getString(TAG_ACAD);

                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    map.put(TAG_ID, Inst_id);
                    map.put(TAG_DESC, Desc);
                    map.put(TAG_SC, Sc);
                    map.put(TAG_SCHED, Sched);
                    map.put(TAG_HOUR, Hour);
                    map.put(TAG_DAY, Day);
                    map.put(TAG_RM, Rm);
                    map.put(TAG_ACAD, Acad);

                    classrecordList.add(map);

                    mylistView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
                    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
                    fab.attachToListView(mylistView);
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(ClassRecord.this, classrecordList,
                            R.layout.list, new String[]{TAG_ID, TAG_DESC, TAG_SC, TAG_SCHED, TAG_HOUR, TAG_DAY, TAG_RM, TAG_ACAD},
                            new int[]{R.id.inst_id, R.id.desc, R.id.subj_code, R.id.sched, R.id.hour, R.id.day, R.id.room, R.id.acad});

                    mylistView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    mylistView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                                    String DESC = ((TextView) (view.findViewById(R.id.desc))).getText().toString();
                                    String CODE = ((TextView) (view.findViewById(R.id.subj_code))).getText().toString();
                                    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("MyApp", MODE_PRIVATE);
                                    preferences.edit().putString("desc", DESC).commit();
                                    preferences.edit().putString("code", CODE).commit();
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(ClassRecord.this, SpecificClassRecord.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);

                        }
                    });
                }
            }catch (JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }




    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_class_record, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case android.R.id.home:
                Intent intent = new Intent(ClassRecord.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: so... what is the problem?

Comment: Stop using PHP's deprecated mysql_ API. Instead see mysqli/PDO *AND* prepared statements

Comment: @RamRaider oh shoot sorry I forgot to include it the problem is when I logged in the populated listview is showing all of the items with different ID's what I want is it should be displaying the items that have my user ID e.g INST-20131296

Comment: how are you passing the ID to the php script?

Comment: @RamRaider well that's the main problem :( the query shoud have a where clause but i have no idea what to do.

Comment: I guess if the variable `ID` is available to your Java program that you could append that to the url like: `private static String url = "http://192.168.0.106/MobileClassRecord/getClassRecord.php?id=<ID_VAR>";` and then in the php use `$id=$_GET['id']` to use in the sql `where` clause

Comment: @RamRaider I finally found out the answer :) thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OKAY! I Found out the answer that what I am seeking :)
credits to @RamRaider his PHP script is my basis in solving my problem :) THANKS A LOT!.

Here is the Script:

```
<?php   
error_reporting(0);
$link = mysql_pconnect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Could not connect");
mysql_select_db("dbmobile_class_record") or die("Could not select database");

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

$id=$_GET['instructor_id'];
// get all items from tb_class_record table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tb_class_record WHERE instructor_id = '$id'") or die(mysql_error());

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

    $response["class_records"] = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            // temp user array
            $class_record = array();
            $class_record["class_record_id"] = $row["class_record_id"];
            $class_record["instructor_id"] = $row["instructor_id"];
            $class_record["subj_code"] = $row["subj_code"];
            $class_record["description"] = $row["description"];
            $class_record["sched_type"] = $row["sched_type"];
            $class_record["hour"] = $row["hour"];
            $class_record["day"] = $row["day"];
            $class_record["room"] = $row["room"];
            $class_record["acad"] = $row["acad"];

            // push recorded items into response array
            array_push($response["class_records"], $class_record);
           }
      // success
     $response["success"] = 1;
}
else {
    // class_record is empty
      $response["success"] = 0;
      $response["message"] = "No Records Found";
}
// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As has been pointed out - it is not a good idea to use the old, now deprecated, `mysql_*` family of functions but rather to use either `mysqli` or `PDO`

Assuming that your Java code can send the ID to the PHP script then I hope you can make use of the following ( Though I'm not too sure I have the fields correct of course - they were guessed based upon the Java code )

```
/* Create your mysqli connection */
$dbhost =   'localhost';
$dbuser =   'root'; 
$dbpwd  =   'xxx'; 
$dbname =   'mydb';

$conn   =   new mysqli( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname );

$arr=array();

/* Prepare your sql & bind the placeholder */
$sql='select 
            `class_records`,
            `instructor_id`,
            `description`,
            `subj_code`,
            `sched_type`,
            `hour`,
            `day`,
            `room`,
            `acad` 
            from `tb_class_record` where `id`=?';

$stmt=$conn->prepare( $sql );
$stmt->bind_param('s', $id );

/*
  assuming you can append the Java ID variable to the url....
  private static String url = "http://192.168.0.106/MobileClassRecord/getClassRecord.php?id=<ID_VAR>";
*/

/* How are you passing the value of ID to PHP? via GET or POST? */
$id=$_GET['id'];

$res=$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bind_result( $class_records, $instructor_id, $description, $subj_code, $sched_type, $hour, $day, $room, $acad );


if( $res ){
    $stmt->fetch();

    $arr['class_records']=array(
        'class_records'=>$class_records,
        'instructor_id'=>$instructor_id,
        'description'=>$description,
        'subj_code'=>$subj_code,
        'sched_type'=>$sched_type,
        'hour'=>$hour,
        'day'=>$day,
        'room'=>$room,
        'acad'=>$acad
    );      
}

$stmt->close();
$conn->close();


/* Send the json response */
echo json_encode( $arr );

/*

*/
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions much appreciated :) I will try it :)

Comment: Im too close :( I thought I can pull out the ID and add it in the url :( it maybe because the url is placed under the class

Comment: hi sir why I am getting this error http://i.imgur.com/7Zr47xq.png
here is the code
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzRtxsi3HCNWRWFlTTcyN0JRMVk/view?usp=sharing
kindly dl sir coz its too long to post here
I updated the code based on what you posted

Comment: It means that there is no field, in the database table, called `instructor_id`. If you note at the beginning of the answer I mentioned that I guessed the table names based upon the Java code - look at the sql, if the fields don't look correct change them and the associated variable names..